# Timer acting weird

Tags: vb.net, timer

Hi guys I have another problem which is all about the timer..the form that I would want to show for 3 seconds is only showing for about half a second. Please help me thanks in advance

Main form code:

```
Private Sub submit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
    'question 1
    If Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" And TextBox1.Text = "third" Then

        Label2.Text = (Label2.Text) + 1

        correctmsg.Show()
        correctmsg.Hide()

        Label1.Text = "Who invented the telephone?"
        Return 'Don't do any more checks this time around

    ElseIf Label1.Text = "Who invented the airplane?" Then
        'Reason ElseIf (In case the question was 'who invented the telephone' then the first errormessage should not not be shown)
        wrongmsg.Show()
        Return

    End If
```

Splash form code:

```
Public Class correctmsg

Private Sub correctmsg_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim mysplash As New correctmsg
    mysplash.Timer1.Interval = 3000

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: your code appears to be hiding it right after it shows.  let the other form's tick event hide it.  Set the interval and enabled in form load though.

Comment: @Plutonix hi sir, can you please elaborate it? thanks

Comment: What happens if you set the interval to 18000? Also, what happens if you take out this line `correctmsg.Hide()`?

Comment: @davidsbro when I take correctmsg.hide() the form will just show and not close itself...even i change the interval the correctmsg form just disappear in half a second

Comment: Okay, I meant try what @Plutonix suggested, plus remove that `correctmsg.hide()`

Comment: If `correctmsg` is the form you are trying to show/hide, it should go invisible when the timer goes off. `correctmsg.Hide()` IS the reason it disappers quickly though and could cause other problems - the CLICK event is/was hiding the form, but elsewhere you could have been creating a new form instance each time. Note also that you should use the new `correctmsg.SHOWMSG` not `correctmsg.Show()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Public Class correctmsg
  ' correctmsg == mysplash ??? so this is a form??


 Private Sub correctmsg_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
      ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

      Timer1.Interval = 3000    ' could be a timer here

 End Sub

 Public Sub ShowMsg
     Timer1.Enabled = true
     me.Visible = True
 End Sub

 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
           ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

     Timer1.Enabled = False
     Me.Visible = False

 End Sub
 End Class
```

I am just showing the form by making it visible.  No need to make a new form.  When the timer expires, hide the form and disable the timer.  To use it:

```
    correctmsg.ShowMsg
    ' this was hiding the form as soon as it shows:
    'correctmsg.Hide()
```

Comment: Thanks sir I just changed the interval time on my correctmsg form because i forgot to....  :)